# Picture and text when clicking on the button. SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

**How to make a picture and text appear when you click on the button?**[image]

```
VStack {
    Image(systemName: "house.fill").resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill) .frame(width: 75, height: 75)
    Text("TEST")
    Spacer().frame(height: 100)
    Button(action: { }) {
        Text("TEST").foregroundColor(Color.white).padding()
    }.background(Color.black) .cornerRadius(10)
}
```

I'm new to swift,
Thanks for any help

Comment: It appears that you've already done it, or is that not your code? If it's not, what have you tried?

Comment: this is video editing

Comment: Okay -- StackOverflow isn't just a code writing service. Can you show what attempt you've made. You are probably able to figure out how to put a button, image, and text on the `View`, right?

Comment: yes i know i already did it

Comment: In general, it's good to have the code you've tried in your question. Luckily, I was able to grab what you had from the comments before you deleted it.

Comment: How could you make that video without having the right code? looks take lots of time from you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `if` clause to conditionally display elements based on a `@State` variable.

I'm using the extra `frame` modifier on the `VStack` that you didn't originally have to make sure that nothing changes position when the `@State` variable changes and the elements inside the stack appear/disappear.

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State private var showImage = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack {
                if showImage {
                    Image(systemName: "house.fill").resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill).frame(width: 75, height: 75)
                    Text("TEST")
                }
            }.frame(height: 100)
            Spacer().frame(height: 100)
            Button(action: { showImage.toggle() }) {
                Text("TEST").foregroundColor(Color.white).padding()
            }.background(Color.black) .cornerRadius(10) }
    }
}
```